# Unable to run DataStax-Studio in Docker on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: docker, cassandra, apple-m1, datastax-studio

I'm trying to install Cassandra and DataStax-studio to access the Cassandra on my `MacBook Pro M1` inside docker.

I was able to pull a Cassandra image and run container.
But when I tried the studio I get this error. Seems the image is built only for intel architecture. I wasn't able to find a specific image for ARM architecture.

Is there a way I can still run DataStax Studio inside Docker running on Apple Mac M1 ?

Below are some terminal output for more clarification.

```
-MBP ~ % docker  image ls 
REPOSITORY            TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
cassandra             latest    f6dfc8a5f3d8   7 days ago    393MB
datastax/dse-studio   latest    79b8a4b75312   7 weeks ago   787MB


-MBP ~ % docker container run -d 79b8a4b75312
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
ce8d20bd23445a20869371fb8e5c8cefbb16e9c968aa1f2870b6b578b6a81e88

-MBP ~ % docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                         NAMES
112e980fe11c   f6dfc8a5f3d8   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9042/tcp, 9160/tcp   hungry_bohr
```

**Update**
This link doesn't provide much help
https://docs.datastax.com/en/install/6.0/install/installDSEDocker.html

Comment: have you installed Rosetta to emulate X86: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` ? see docs: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/

Comment: Yeah, that's the first part before starting the docker installation. But did not explicitly do anything in local Docker to run with rosetta-2.  Just installed Rosetta-2 and then installed docker and started

Answer (score 1):

There's no ARM support for Studio.

There were some changes to the Cassandra builds that would allow installation on ARM machines but it's not officially supported yet so there's a chance that you'll run into some issues at some point.

I'm going to reach out to the Studio developers here at DataStax and will post an update here as appropriate. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** - Can you try to override it by specifying `--platform linux/amd64` with `docker run`?

P.S. Studio only works with DSE and [Astra](https://dtsx.io/3oUbsNq). It won't work with open-source Cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: I applied that and seems the error is gone by I'm still unable to access the due from browser .....This is the actual command I ran.......`docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept -p 9091:9091  --name my-studio --platform linux/amd64 -d datastax/dse-studio`

Comment: Even after 10 mins I get this same log for my dse-studio container .....`-MBP ~ % docker logs 76
Starting DataStax Studio
Starting Studio. This may take a few minutes. You will be notified here when Studio is ready.`